# MVC Form does not pass Model on Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following MVC View and Controller.  When I submit the form. It pass in the Id instead of the ChangeUserViewModel.

View:

```
@model AppTransactionsManagement.Models.ChangeUserViewModel
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "UsersAdmin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```js
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        private async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangeUserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Get the user manager and user. (if the user is not found, user will be null)
                ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);


                if (user == null)
                {
                    return PartialView("_ChangePassword");
                }
                else
                {

                    user.PasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.Password);

                    UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(user.Id.ToString());
                    //Save Changes
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                        return PartialView("_ChangePassword");

                    }
                }
            }
            return PartialView("_ChangePassword");

        }
```

Model:

```js
 public class ChangeUserViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show ChangeUserViewModel?

Comment: What do you mean "instead of", is your model just empty with only the Id field populated? I'm not seeing how and int could replace your model. How are you determining this is happening?

Comment: Post your view model, usual culprit is when the model you are passing in is missing fields and the framework has an issue mapping what is passed in to the object it is expecting.

Comment: I added the model. @mxmissile - The param the controller received is the Id and not the Model.  I find this out while debugging it.

Comment: `The param the controller received is the Id and not the Model.` How do you get Id from `ChangePassword(ChangeUserViewModel model)` without declaring `Id` as a  parameter?

Comment: @Win can a private `ActionResult` method be marked as `HttpPost`? I thought making them `private` made them inaccessible

Comment: @adiga Good catch; I just notice it. Now, I'm lost why OP said `It pass in the Id instead of the ChangeUserViewModel.`.

Comment: Thank you @adiga...you save me hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have marked the method as `private`, which will make it inaccessible. You can't `POST` to a private method. This is most likely your problem. Change it to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangeUserViewModel model)
{
   ......
   ......
}
```

Comment: The way the OP has their `EditorFor` setup is correct.  If they change to what you've suggested, the class `form-control` does not get applied.

Comment: @T_Roy oh you're right, I was thinking of `TextBoxFor`. Thanks.

Comment: You are the man @adiga.  I've been at it for 3 hrs and I never once thinking of looking at the access modifier. Eventually I would have find it but god only knows how long it would have taken.  You save me hours. Thank you, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use model binding in your controller action.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword([Bind(Include = "Id, Email, Password")]ChangeUserViewModel model) {}
```